# What format does data input have to be for Python's json.loads?

Tags: python, sql, json, amazon-redshift, udf

I'm trying to use `json.loads` to parse data in a Redshift database table. I've stripped out the function to test in a Python script and am having trouble understanding what's happening.

The code I'm using is:

```
import json
j="'['Bars', 'American (Traditional)', 'Nightlife', 'Restaurants']'"

def trythis(item, reverse):
    if not j:
        return '1'
    try:
         arr = json.loads(j)
    except ValueError:
        return '2'
    if not ascending:
        arr = sorted(arr, reverse=True)
    else:
        arr = sorted(arr)
    return json.dumps(arr)

print trythis(j, True)
```

And this is returning `2`.

I've tried changing the input variable to `j="['Bars', 'American (Traditional)', 'Nightlife', 'Restaurants']"` but that hasn't worked. What format does my entry value need to be?

Comment: Ah thanks. Would you recommend using something like `str.replace` to replace the inner single quotes to double quotes?

Comment: I would just switch the your use of single quotes for double quotes. It's less confusing for anyone reading your code.

Comment: You shouldn't try to create JSON by hand, there are a number of details that you're not likely to get right. Use a library function that creates JSON from a data structure, such as `json.dumps()`.

Comment: Where did your single quoted list come from?

Comment: It came from Yelp's data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input string `j` is not valid JSON. JSON doesn't allow the use of single quotes (`'`) to denote string values.

Try switching the quotes: `'["Bars", "American (Traditional)", "Nightlife", "Restaurants"]'`

The JSON specification is an excellent resource for determining if your input is valid JSON. You can find it here: http://www.json.org/

Comment: Thanks. The data actually isn't JSON format, but I was able to just replace the single quotes with double quotes on the SQL side before using the function. Not the best way, but all I need is something that works.